# How to restore the layout of react-grid-layout without using React

Tags: react-grid-layout

I am using this library and feel great:
https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout

One issue, how to replicate the layout from it using plain HTML / CSS / JS, such that I can reproduce this layout in another framework like Angular?